# PendingIntents: why only one of the 2 works?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Hi and thanks for your help.

Please I am trying to use an AlarmManager to start and stop Activities during the week.

Now I am confronted with this problem that I do not understand.

For each day of the week I create 2 PendingIntents:

- one for starting the activity
- one for killing the activity

you can see the code below.

Now the problem is that:

**- only the second PendingIntent fires off**

(and starts the Activity, thereticaally it should stop it but since the first PendingIntent never goes off the second PendingIntent starts the activity instead of closing it).

**- Apparently the first PendingIntent never goes off !!!!**

```
        / INTENT THAT SHOULD START THE ACTIVITY
        Intent sthu = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);

        PendingIntent psthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, sthu, 0);

        Calendar calSet7 = Calendar.getInstance();

        calSet7.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet7.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet7.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hsthu);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.MINUTE, msthu);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet7.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, psthu);

        // INTENT THAT SHOULD KILL THE ACTIVITY
        Intent fthu = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        fthu.putExtra("finish", true);
        PendingIntent pfthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, fthu, 0);
        Calendar calSet8 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet8.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet8.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet8.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hfthu);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mfthu);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet8.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pfthu);
```

---

AFTER THE SUGGESTED CHANGE:

apparently now only the 1st PendingIntent goes off:

```
     Intent sthu = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        sthu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent psthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 1, sthu, 0);

        Calendar calSet7 = Calendar.getInstance();

        calSet7.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet7.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet7.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hsthu);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.MINUTE, msthu);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet7.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        //calSet.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet7.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, psthu);
        Log.e("","setto alarm per giovedì");
        // INTENT 
        Intent fthu = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        fthu.putExtra("finish", true);
        PendingIntent pfthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 2, fthu, 0);
        Calendar calSet8 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet8.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet8.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet8.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hfthu);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mfthu);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet8.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet8.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pfthu);
```

---

THE PURPOSE OF THE 2ND PENDINGINTENT IS

TO TELL THE ACTIVITY (STARTED BY THE 1ST PENDINGINTENT)

TO FINISH ITSELF.

**(**

**To sum up:**

**1st PendingIntent to start the Activity,**

**2nd PendingIntent to thell the Activity to finish**

**)**

Here is the code of the Activity:

```
 public class VideoActivty extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
    + R.raw.ingress);
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
    setContentView(videoHolder);

    videoHolder.start();

@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent i){
    //HERE I TRY TO TELL THE ACTIVITY (VIA THE SECOND INTENT) TO SHUT DOWN

  if( i.getBooleanExtra("finish",false) ){
      finish();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: At what time  after you want to close your Activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the request code of PendingIntent (of any one). They should not be same.

like

```
PendingIntent psthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 1 /*Changed Here*/, sthu, 0);

PendingIntent pfthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 2 /*Changed Here*/, fthu, 0);
```

---

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to both intents which you are passing to each PendingIntents.

> Note that the activity will be started outside of the context of an
>   existing activity, so you must use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   launch flag in the Intent.

Read more about [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

---

What is working for me is..

Register Alarm for  only launch Activity

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)(getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

        Intent sthu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoActivty.class);
        sthu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        sthu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 

        PendingIntent psthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, sthu, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar startWhen = new GregorianCalendar();
        startWhen.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1000);

        //calSet.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startWhen.getTimeInMillis(),
                60 * 1000, psthu);
        Log.e("","setto alarm per giovedì");
```

And call below method at `onCreate` of `VideoActivty`

```
private void registerActivityCloseAlarm() {
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)(getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
        Intent fthu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoActivty.class);
        fthu.putExtra("finish", true);
        fthu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        fthu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pfthu = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 2, fthu, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar endWhen = new GregorianCalendar();
        endWhen.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 2000);

        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, endWhen.getTimeInMillis(), pfthu);
    }
```

This will work

Comment: And one more thing instead of using 0 as flag consider FLAG_ONE_SHOT or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT into PendingIntents

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar thank you very much, I must report FAILURE: even if set Add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to both only the 1st PendingIntent fires off :-((((

Comment: I would suggest you to verify your code with using constants for calender attributes like minutes or seconds, and then let me know what happens

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar even after using constants for minutes and hours the result is not changing: NOW apparently only the 1st PendingIntent goes off...

Comment: And what about after changing the flags

Comment: @ Pankaj Kumar please see my edits, which flags do you suggest i should use???  THANKS A LOT !!!!!